# Why does {{ user.getPhotoUrl(64) }} point towards storage/runtime and not to storage/userprofiles?

Tags: redirect, user-profile

I am trying to load user profile pictures (the Craft ones), but they don't load. The `getPhotoUrl()` seems to point to the wrong folder(?).

The profile images seem to be stored in the userprofiles folder by default

```
{% set users = craft.users %}

{% for user in users %}
    <div class="searchresults"><a href="/profile/{{ user }}">{{ user }}</a>

    {% if user.getPhotoUrl %}
        <img src="{{ user.getPhotoUrl(64) }}" class="profile_search_picture" alt="{{ entry.user.getFullName }}"/>
    {% else %}
        <img src="/img/fallback.png" class="profile_search_picture" alt="{{ entry.user.getFullName }}"/> 
    {% endif %}

</div>
{% endfor %}
```

---

> 2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/tempuploads/field_3/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/tempuploads/field_4/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/tempuploads/user_1/field_3/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/tempuploads/user_1/field_4/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/temp/uploads/userphotos/harry/, but could not.
>   2017/04/24 11:24:10 [error] [application] Tried to read the folder contents of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/temp/uploads/userphotos/remco/, but could not.

---

the console gives this error

```
GET http://localhost/cpresources/userphotos/remco/64/17492405_10212330524487585_7776812525773615973_o.jpg?x=UoEZXg1dH net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the `/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage/runtime/assets/sources/` log entries are related to the request when `getResourceUrl()` is called.  Of if they are, they are elsewhere in the request and not as a direct result of calling `getResourceUrl`()`.

The error in the console seems like the one to investigate.  Based on `net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`, I'd check to make sure that `craft/storage` is recursively writable by PHP as a starting point.

Comment: I've checked the permissions and all seems fine here. Even used `chmod -R 777 /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/craft/storage` to confirm.

Answer (score 1):

@cole sorted it! I am hosting craft locally and my localhost used the port number as part of it's URL. I switched the ports to `80/81/3306` which took the `8888` port out of the url and also loaded all images.